# invalid property value scss function

Tags: css, angular, sass

I've set up some scss files/folders that load in the following way (Angular project)

1) Settings - which have colour settings for the project, as well as some functions
2) Files and folders that define variables fonts, widths, etc. for the components and pages'
3) Files and folders that use the variables for classes

The problem I'm having is; the functions I've created in the settings file are not working and giving an invalid property value

[image]

_settings: loaded first

```
$brand-colours: (
    text:                       #2F2F2F,
    text-white:                 #FFFFFF,
    primary-bg-colour:          #F3F3F3,
    heading:                    #5C1544,
    border:                     #969696,
    borderSecondary:            #DCDCDC,
    primary:                    #0068AA,
    secondary:                  #D11E4F,
    focusState:                 #F6C037,
    focusBackgroundState:       #FFF7E6,
    hoverState:                 #00B2CF,
    hoverBackgroundState:       #00B2CF,
    activeState:                #00B2CF,
    errorState:                 #D91F26,
    validState:                 #C5DA46,
    panelLightBlue:             rgb(0, 0, 0)
);

@function brand-colour($colour, $colours: $brand-colours) {
    @return map-get($brand-colours, $colour);
}
```

_body: loaded second

```
$body-bg-colour:                brand-color('primary-bg-colour') !default;
$body-bg-colour-1:              #FFFFFF !default;
$body-colour:                   brand-colour('text');
$body-font-family:              'ProxinaNova';
```

_body: loaded last

```
body {
    background-color: $body-bg-colour-1;
    color: $body-colour;
    font-family: $body-font-family;

    @include hg-mq('med') {
        background-color: $body-bg-colour;
    }
}
```

in style.scss

```
@import 'settings/settings';
@import 'base/body';
@import 'shared/body';
```

The reason I'm doing this way is that I want to have multiple apps using the same code (last loaded) and just update 1st and second loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a tiny mistake. The `brand-colour` function's 2nd argument is `$colours`, but you're not using the argument, you're using the default value. Here's a [DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/ff611bdf777a4212e32ec6e039e3df7d)...

The `brand-colour` function is just `map-get` whose 2nd argument has a default value. It doesn't add any value + adds unnecessary complexity to your code. I'd recommend just using `map-get`...